# Gitlab: ssh with public key is asking for password

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have a gitlab docker container running on a server. There I have an account where I have added my local public key. When I use `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.example.com`, I'm getting this logs:

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.7.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.example.com [...............] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.example.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:FGVojuHn/a0Ed9E0nr2KlZ+HDSGFp8YoFGxmIQKI8nU
debug1: Host 'gitlab.example.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:N4PzqZeVZdEgF2XSGUQk0QjfpuElRF4yetk3bykCaaE /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I also tried it with `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.example.com -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa`, because thats the name of my key file. But that was neither working. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you register other key in gitlab rather than `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: I have a second key registered in gitlab. But that was nearly a year ago and I'm not sure where it is from.

Comment: I believe you can view key fingerprint in GitLab, then compare with your local key.